# Adding new translations with poedit in ZF2

Tags: localization, internationalization, zend-framework2, poedit

I'm trying to add a `.mo` file for en_US translations but I keep getting this error:

`Updating the catalog failed. Click on 'Details >>' for details.`

And the content is:

`execvp(xgettext--force-po, -o, /tmp/poeditf0AcvR/0extrated.pot <...> ) failed with error 2!`

Answer (score 0):

You know what's a much better place to report problems with applications you use than SO? As a rule of thumb, *its developer* is best able and most qualified to help. It's a good idea to provide relevant details, too (this evergreen is worth every second spent reading it, please do: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html), such as version of the app, your platform, specifics of what you're actually doing ("add a .mo" isn't quite as descriptive as it could be).

Seeing that Poedit is apparently trying to launch a program named `xgettext--force-po`, which quite obviously doesn't exist, my blind guess would be that you went to Poedit's preferences, messed with the settings for whatever extractor you use for this and accidentally removed a space after `xgettext` from the extraction command in there.

Remove the extractor, quit Poedit and let it recreate it.